# Hat Dash "High Score" on the top left corner always shows last round's score, not the highest score - Winter Bash

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I play Hat Dash sometimes, and I always see on the top left corner that it shows that my highest score is always the score I got last round:

[image: Bug]

But as you can see above, my highest score is not 48, it's 1,447.

I suspect this is a bug.

We should either change the number to the "actual" high score, or change the label name to "Last round score".

---

@kylejrp says that it's the high score of every session...

That's true, I checked it, but I still think the name should be changed.

Comment: This seems to track the high score for your individual session. It works for me if I break the session high score.

Comment: @kylejrp That's true, but than the name is a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug, though the naming is indeed somewhat confusing.

When you click the "Hat Dash!" button to start playing, a new session is created, and lasts until you click the "All done running" button.

The "High Score" is the current session high score. It doesn't load your best score from all past sessions.

This is also the behavior of the [original game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Game), which has no leaderboard at all.

Comment: Yeah you can check my "Edited:" part, I say about that, but then the name is a bit confusing...